# str.find(sub) get the last character index, not the first of sub

Tags: python, string, find

I'm wondering if there is a built-in method to accomplish this:

```
>>> my_str = 'This is just a test string'
>>> to_find = 'just'
>>> my_str.find(to_find)
8                                            # what I normally get
>>> my_str.find(to_find) + len(to_find) - 1
11                                           # what I want to get
>>>
```

Is this the better and "pythonic" way to get my desired result?

Comment: what if there are multiple occurrence of words?

Comment: there is no built-in method. You version is very good solution.

Comment: With re module: `re.search(to_find, my_str).end() - 1`

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri at this moment I don't care about other occurrences, I just need the first.

Comment: ok, I understand that there is no built-in method for this and that mine is a nice solution (thank you @furas), also I learned another way to achieve the same goal (thank you @MYGz).
[OT] why this question was downvoted? Just asking, I'm relative new to SO, maybe was too trivial or poorly worded? Let me know so I can improve in the future.

Comment: I assume some down voted because they thought it too basic.  But who knows?